# Read MS Access file (.mdb) without ms provider on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, ms-access, .net-core

I am familiar with reading mdb files with use of Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0. My case is that I would like to create .net core application, which could be run on Linux. Real question: how to read .mdb file on linux(and windows) using .net core?

I tried EntityFramework.Core.Jet but with no success.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55696920/error-could-not-load-type-system-data-oledb-oledbconnection-from-assembly-system

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

- Free and open-source ODBC driver from [MDB Tools](https://github.com/mdbtools/mdbtools)
- Wrap `mdb-export` (perf comparable with odbc) or `mdb-json` from [MDB Tools](https://github.com/mdbtools/mdbtools) with [CliWrap](https://github.com/Tyrrrz/CliWrap) (for read-only purposes)
- Use Jackcess via IKVM
- Commercial [ODBC driver from Easysoft](https://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-access-driver/)
- [ODBTP](https://odbtp.sourceforge.net/) to remotely access Win32-based databases (you need some windows based server with your MS Access database)

I described in more detail how you can do this here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75565707/2828480

I'm not sure what provides the most complete feature-set if you need to do something other than basic read operations. I've never tested ODBC driver from Easysoft but since it's commercial I'd assume it's comparable to the official Windows one. Other than that maybe Jackcess if you don't care about SQL or UCanAccess if you care about SQL.

Unfortunately there aren't any other options I can think of. If you have other suggestions feel free to edit or comment.